# Function returning static variable C++

Tags: c++, static

I fail to understand why the following program wrong:

```
 int& getID(){
   static int r = 0;
   return r++;
 }
```

main:

```
 int main(){
   int a = getID();
   std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

Why returning a static variable as described creates problems and not returning 
the wanted value?

Comment: no it wont print anything.
my guess its because of the ++, but i cant understand why, its supposed to return a reference to r but non is given

Comment: Could you, please, post complete programs in the future? - sscce.org

Comment: This shouldn't compile: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’`

Comment: I took the freedom to correct the indentation for better readability and add missing identifier - std::cout, because without that the program would be incorrect.

Comment: It should not compile. `r++` returns `int`, not `int &`. Try `r++; return r;` instead.

Comment: `r++` doesn't "return" anything. It _evaluates_ to a _prvalue_.

Comment: This isn't correct C++, since temporaries cannot bind to non-constant references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using post-increment(r++ as opposed to ++r).  The result of post-increment is a temporary, and you are trying to return a reference to that temporary.  You can't do that.  If you want to return a reference to r, then you can use pre-increment, or you can just do the increment, then in a separate statement, return r.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return a reference to `r` but a reference to `r`'s value before it was incremented. And that is probably lost in action.

Try

```
r++;
return r;
```

or

```
return ++r;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're running into is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

`r++` returns a temporary, and it's UB returning temporaries by reference.

On my platform, for example, it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Make your function return `int` not `int &` and all will be well. You want to return the value of the new id, not a reference to the function's internals.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about prefix and postfix operator and how [they are implemented](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14).

Basically, `++i` does this (prefix):

```
i += 1;
return i;
```

And `i++` does (postfix):

```
ans = i;
i += 1;
return ans;
```

According to mentioned page, only the prefix `operator++` returns reference to upgraded variable. Postfix (`i++`) returns new variable.